# Setting up Django and Mysql on Mac os

Tags: mysql, django, macos

I know there are tones of questions like that but sadly none of them resolved my problems and as I am new to django I don't know what is wrong.
So I installed django and mysql successfully, then the django-mysql package. When try to import the `MySQLdb` in python (running in the terminal) it works.
But my question is: how do you start mysql and create a database? And how to "link" it to django?
I tried running `mysql` but it doesn't work. So I tried `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql` which throws an error `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`.

What do I have to do?

Comment: Your question is answered in [MySQL's](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/automatic-start.html) and [Django's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/#database-setup) documentation.

Comment: If you use mysql, so to create a database you can use `phpmyadmin`, a GUI based database manager. And there is no need ot start mysql as it get started automatically on system startup. But you can manually stop, restart it as well. Check the mysql documentation.

Comment: go into /usr/local/mysql/bin/  and run ./mysqld_safe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your system preferences - there should be a MySQL icon on the bottom. There you can start it.

[image: system preferences]
[image: mysql status]

Also I recommend to install [MySQLWorkbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) to manage your db

Answer (score 0):

I think that @init3 already answered the question regarding how to start mysql. How do you "link" your database to a django project? Well, in your settings.py file you find something like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',        # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'my_database_name',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': 'my_mysql_user',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': 'my_mysql_password',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

So change `NAME`, `USER` and `PASSWORD` accordingly and Django will use that database to create tables and populate fields.

Comment: Yes for the django settings I know this part. But the thing is I don't know how to get access to mysql through the terminal or Sequel Pro. So I can't create the database. I've always used Mamp for PHP projects so I don't know to set the mysql I installed independently.

Comment: Well, I can't help you with OSX but in linux you do this: mysql -u username -p. Then a prompt allows you to input your password. After that, you create a database using CREATE DATABASE database_name and that's it.

Comment: The mysql commands is not found... I am gonna check if mysql is properly installed. Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. Yes, maybe it's not installed. If you type mysql --help you should get which commands are allowed.